# How to link one modifier to more objects?

Tags: modifiers

I have hundreds of objects, and I'd like to add a modifier to them with the same parameters. Not copy, but link.
There are tutorials for older verions, but this possibilitz disappeared in this version (2.93).

Can anybody know about it?

Comment: AFAIK modifiers cannot be linked like this.

Comment: You can't.  The closest I know is to copy the modifiers, then if you have to adjust them, copy them again; but this is not an optimal workflow.

Comment: As above, you can't link modifiers for different objects.
However!
If you have multiple objects with the same modifier you can select them all and adjust any value in the modifier when holding the ALT key, and it will be changed for all selected objects. btw - this works for any value, not only modifier settings.

Comment: This ALT + param change trick may be very handy sometimes, I never used before. But I can't understand, why modifier linking was removed completely. Blender is strongly based on datablocks, and as I think, modifier parameters are fully datablock-friendly.